# Format of Time registry value in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Files entries

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office

What is the information in the Time registry value in the entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Files?

I see (example):0x01c99b84|0x11990880

I'm pretty sure that the first "half" (prior to the bar character) is the file modified time (probably in File Time format.  I'm not sure what the 2nd "half" of the entry is.

Entries were made by SharePoint checkouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx is a good overview of different time formats.  In this case, it looks like an NT time (100 ns intervals since Jan 1, 1600.)

Filetime is 64-bit.  You need to combine the two 32-bit values together, i.e. 0x01c99b8411990880.

Is this registry key documented?  If not, you shouldn't be depending on it.